# Will an Omnipotent being ever make an change into the state of this reality

Tags: reality, omnipotence

Being able to make any change to the state of reality pretty much makes everything an meaningless endeavor.

In my view an Omnipotent being will know everything and anything in it's entirety. He/She will understand that it doesn't matter what the current state of this reality is right now, it will roll either this way or that way. Anyway it will be meaningless to the Omnipotent.

My question is, will he/she make a change into the state of the reality knowing that it's irrelevant OR it will just freeze into an eternal motionlessness?

Comment: You seem to be confusing omniscient and omnipotent in your second paragraph. And then adding a claim that does not obviously follow (that any change wi not matter), which seems to be the hinge of your question. Can you make clearer why you maintain that no change an omnipotent being can make will matter?

Comment: @virmaior If one takes a broad enough interpretation of omnipotence, omnipotence could imply omniscience. If knowledge is power, then an all-powerful being would presumably possess the power of omniscience.

Comment: @DavidH I see the logic that makes it true that an omnipotent being could be omniscient, but that's logic that should be spelled out as it less than obvious. But more importantly, I don't see the jump to the conclusion that such a being would understand the futility of its actions, because I don't see why it would conclude its actions are futile.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by whether the being will "make a change into the state of the reality" - do you mean "make a change to"? "move into"?

Answer (score 1):

`Being able to make any change to the state of reality pretty much makes everything an meaningless endeavor.` - Most Christians would say something slightly different - creation was *unnecessary* for God to do, which is different than it being *meaningless*. Since it was an unnecessary act, Christians usually say that creation itself is an act of Love, and therefore the meaning behind everything in creation is Love. For our part, the way CS Lewis described it is that the actions we take help shape our immortal soul, and so our actions derive meaning from this process aside from whatever happens in the material world. From this perspective, even if the universe "will just freeze into an eternal motionlessness" there is still meaning in what we do, for us and for God.

Since reality has meaning for God, it is not as far that goes dismissible that God would change reality. This is a different question from "Does God change reality?" It seems quite plausible that God *could* and *would* change reality but *chooses not to*. Different religious traditions (even within Christianity) have different opinions on this.

Answer (score 0):

> Being able to make any change to the state of reality pretty much makes everything an meaningless endeavor.

I'd question this assumption; suppose I'm a writer and I am faced with a blank page, I can choose to write whatever I want, in whatever script I want or just doodle over it.

All of these acts possess meaning to the extent that thought has gone into it.

Analogously, it doesn't follow that being able to make any change to reality, renders reality into a meaningless category.